# Translating propery name of html link

Tags: yii2, translation

How can I translate the property named *Create NEW* inside the link?

```
Html::a('Create NEW', ['create'], ['class' => 'btn btn-success']),
```

I tried this

```
$var = Yii::t('app', 'Create NEW');
Html::a($var, ['create'], ['class' => 'btn btn-success']);
```

but the link gets lost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can  place the translation inside the link widget:

```
Html::a(Yii::t('app', 'Create NEW'), ['create'], ['class' => 'btn btn-success']),
```